# Is there a way to convert pyplot.imshow() object to numpy array?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, matplotlib

I need to visualize a 2D numpy array. I am using `pyplot` for this.

Here's the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot

img = pyplot.imshow( radiance_val )
#radiance_val is a 2D numpy array of size = ( 512, 512 ) 
#filled with np.float32 values

pyplot.show()
```

I am getting the output as expected.

Now my question is, is there any way of converting "img" in the above code from pyplot type to numpy type. I need this so that I can load the visualization as opencv image and perform further processing on it. I am using python 2.7, 32 bit.

---

**EDIT 1**: after Thorsten Kranz's solution

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from cStringIO import StringIO

frame1 = plt.gca()
frame1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
frame1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))

buffer_ = StringIO()
plt.savefig( buffer_, format = "png", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0 )
buffer_.seek(0)

image = PIL.Image.open( buffer_ )

ar = np.asarray(image)
cv.imshow( 'a', ar )
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here I am getting a runtime error from MS VC++ runtime library after the program terminates. My better guess is that it is because of the open "buffer_". But I am getting the required output.

---

**EDIT 2**: closing the buffer using

```
buffer_.close()
```

did not solve the runtime error

Comment: I added buffer_.close() as mentioned by Thorsten Kranz but the runtime error occurs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you really need the marker ticks and such,

```
im._rgba_cache
```

gives you direct access to the MxNx4 `numpy` array that is the color mapped data.

If you just want the color mapped data, you can by pass `imshow` entirely and directly color-map the data your self (see [guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) for picking your color map)

```
my_cm = maplotlib.cm.get_cmap('Reds')
normed_data = (data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data))
mapped_data = my_cm(normed_data)
```

which will give you back a MxNx4 array mapped between `0` and `1`,

```
mapped_datau8 = (255 * my_cm(normed_data)).astype('uint8')
```

or

```
mapped_data = my_cm(normed_data, bytes=True)
```

will convert it to unsigned ints.

`matplotlib` includes a range of normalization code, [see here](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html?highlight=lognorm#matplotlib.colors.Normalize).

[`get_cmap` doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap) and [colormap gallery](http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/teaching/matplotlib/#colormaps)

edit: fixed oversight pointed out at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880947/380231

Comment: Wow, your solution preserves the original image dimensions which was my next question. thank you very much. And I am not getting any runtime error too.

Comment: By the way, its `my_cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')`. And is there any specific purpose for passing `'jet'` in `'my_cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('jet')'` ? I ask because I am getting same output without passing.

Comment: if you want to use a different color map ex, `get_cmap('jet_r')` you can call them by name.  You get the same thing because if you do not pass an argument it returns the default (which unless you have changed it is `'jet'`).

Comment: `my_cm( data )` is not producing correct map for `numpy.float` data type. Its working fine for `numpy.int` data type.

Comment: @Yash You should open a new question with that issue.

Comment: Trying to directly access the numpy array using `im._rgba_cache` throws `AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute '_rgba_cache'`. What's that `im` in our first snippet?

Comment: @FaCoffee Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: As mentioned by @FaCoffee, what is `im` in `im._rgba_cache` in the first line of the answer?

Answer (score 5):

Ar you sure you want to convert the return value of the method or the whole plot?

For the latter, you should try:

- Save the plot to a StringIO-buffer image using `savefig`
- Load the image from this buffer, using PIL or opencv
- Convert it to a numpy array

See sample below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from cStringIO import StringIO

plt.imshow(np.random.random((20,20)))
buffer_ = StringIO()
plt.savefig(buffer_, format = "png")
buffer_.seek(0)
image = PIL.Image.open(buffer_)
ar = np.asarray(image)
buffer_.close()
```

Look into `savefig`-`*args` and `**kwargs` for more options, e.g., dpi, background color, transparency, padding etc.

If you jsut want the color coded image, without axes, labels, etc., I'd still do the same, just use

```
plt.subplots_adjust(0,0,1,1)
```

to extend the axes over the whole figure. Take care of the `aspect` of you plot, otherwise mpl might shrink your axes again.

Comment: Awesome this worked for me. Thank you very much. I exactly wanted what your solution is providing. I have a problem though. I put the script into a file and executed it. After the program terminates, I get a run-time error from Microsoft VC++ runtime library ( this application has asked the runtime to terminate it in an unusual way ). I have edited my post to include the code. Can you please tell me how to correct it. My better guess is the open "buffer_". But there is no option to close open file in PIL.

Comment: buffer_ is a StringIO object, nothing related to PIL. You can release all used resources by calling `buffer_.close()`. Though I'm not sure if this will solve your problem. Nevertheless, before we search on, try this.

Comment: I included buffer_.close() to no effect. I still am getting a runtime error, same as mentioned before, in my previous comment. Please find the full code in my post. I have edited it after your solution.

Comment: You could try to replace `from cStringIO import StringIO` with `from StringIO import StringIO`. This might be a little bit slower (irrelevant here) but reduces dependencies to compiled C code.

Comment: I must add that no error is being raised if i type in line by line into python IDLE...... . Error occurs only when i put the code into .py file and run it.

Comment: Does it also occur if you don't use matplotlib and only put `np.random.random((20,20))` into `cv.imshow`? Maybe setting another mpl backend can help, e.g. `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("Agg")` at the beginnig of your script.

Comment: cv.imshow works only with 'uint8' data type which is unlike the data type returned by np.random.random((20,20)). And I tried setting another mpl backend as you suggested. The runtime error still persists but I am getting the correct putput. I think its some kind of bug. I will post it on [bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org)

Answer (score 1):

here I found a much more sample to convert an array to rgba,
I wanted to convert the spectrogram to rgb images with the magma cmap, and here's what I did;

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='magma')
sm.set_clim(spect.min(), spect.max())
im = sm.to_rgba(spect)

plt.imshow(im)
plt.title(im.shape)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer inspired from @Thorsten Kranz

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import io
plt.imshow(np.random.random((20,20)))
with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    plt.savefig(buffer, format = "png")
    buffer.seek(0)
    image = Image.open(buffer)
    ar = np.asarray(image)
print(ar.shape)
```