# pyplot.cm instance is producing different results for same values but different data type

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This question is in continuation of the solution provided by [tcaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380231/tcaswell) (answer #2) for my question: [Is there a way to convert pyplot.imshow() object to numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869321/is-there-a-way-to-convert-pyplot-imshow-object-to-numpy-array)

Consider the following python code:

```
import pylab
import numpy as np

a = np.array( ( 30, 129 ) , dtype = np.float32 )
b = np.array( ( 30, 129 ) , dtype = np.int32 )
my_cm = pylab.cm.get_cmap('jet')
a_mapped_data = my_cm( a )
b_mapped_data = my_cm( b )
```

I am using a small array to save space, but this is what is seen even when large arrays are used.

The results:

```
>>> a
array([  30.,  129.], dtype=float32)

>>> b
array([ 30, 129])

>>> a_mapped_data
array([[ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ],
       [ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ]])

>>> b_mapped_data
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.5028463 ,  1.        ,  0.46489564,  1.        ]])
```

I don't seem to understand the behavior here. Even though the values are same, `cm.get_map()` instance is producing different results for `numpy.int32` and `numpy.float32` data types. Is there something wrong with the code above? Please help out with this. I need to plot 2D arrays of type numpy.float.

I am using python 2.7.3 32bit on Windows7 x64 Home Basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docstring of `my_cm.__call__`:

```
*X* is either a scalar or an array (of any dimension).
If scalar, a tuple of rgba values is returned, otherwise
an array with the new shape = oldshape+(4,). If the X-values
are integers, then they are used as indices into the array.
If they are floating point, then they must be in the
interval (0.0, 1.0).
Alpha must be a scalar between 0 and 1, or None.
If bytes is False, the rgba values will be floats on a
0-1 scale; if True, they will be uint8, 0-255.
```

Note the difference between how floats and ints are treated.

Comment: So if have an array like `[12.02, 1.122][0.23, 7.543]` can i divide the entire array with the largest place value applicable (in this case 100) and plot it? It should produce right results, right?

Comment: Well, I tried dividing by the largest place value. It don't think it gives the right result.....

Comment: what do you mean place value?

Comment: Maybe `s = (a - a.min()) / a.ptp(); a_mapped = my_cm(s)`; that linearly maps the data to the interval [0,1].

Comment: @Yash gah, sorry I messed up.  Fixed my other answer.

Comment: @tcaswell: i mean decimal place value

Comment: @tcaswell: i meant decimal place value. I just wanted to normalize the values which was later suggested by WarrenWeckesser in a better way. I saw your fix in the previous answer too. I am now getting exactly what wanted. Thank you for taking out your time to answer my questions.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thank you for your input. It worked. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The script below performs a color map on the input data and the map is converted to image as is, without using `pylab.imshow` or `pylab.pcolor` and without any scales or borders.

```
import pylab
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random( (512, 512) )*100
# a is a 2D array of random data not in the range of 0.0 to 1.0

# normalize the data
normed_a = ( a - a.min() )/( a.max() - a.min() )

# now create an instance of pylab.cm.get_cmap()
my_cm = pylab.cm.get_cmap('jet_r')

# create the map
mapped_a = my_cm( normed_a )

# to display the map, opencv is being used
# import opencv
import cv2 as cv

# convert mapped data to 8 bit unsigned int
mapped_au8 = (255 * mapped_a).astype('uint8')

# show the image
cv.imshow( 'a', mapped_au8 )
cv.waitKey( 0 )
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

**EDIT :** Return type `cm.get_cmap` instance is of RGBA format but OpenCV by default operates on BGR format. Hence before displaying any image obtained by converting return values of `cm.get_cmap()` instance as in the above code, convert it to BGR format ( *The ALPHA channel is anyway stripped by default in opencv before the image is displayed so dont bother to convert it into BGRA unless necessary* ). The code below gives a better explanation:

```
mapped_au8 = (255 * mapped_a).astype('uint8')

#convert mapped_au8 into BGR fromat before display
mapped_u8 = cv.cvtColor( mapped_au8, cv.COLOR_RGBA2BGR )

# show the image
cv.imshow( 'a', mapped_au8 )
cv.waitKey( 0 )
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14880766/3) to the question [pyplot.cm instance is producing different results for same values but different data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880766/pyplot-cm-instance-is-producing-different-results-for-same-values-but-different) by the OP [Yash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1759979/yash) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>