# How to deal with nan when converting 2-D Numpy array into a GeoTIFF file

Tags: python, numpy, raster, gdal, geotiff

I want to convert a 2-D Numpy array into a 3-band (RGB) GeoTIFF file.
You will find below a piece of my code and this is what I intend to do:

1. get the array "topo" (composed of nan values)
2. convert the numpy array into RGB (as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869321/is-there-a-way-to-convert-pyplot-imshow-object-to-numpy-array/14877059#14877059))
3. List item

I really don't know how to deal with the nan values ... in step 2 and 3.
Could you help me?
Thanks

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from osgeo import gdal, osr
    # My image array
    topo = self.topo # topo is a numpy array
    lat = self.Y
    lon = self.X
    # normalize array values to [0,1]
    cmin = np.nanmin(topo)
    cmax = np.nanmax(topo)
    my_cm = plt.get_cmap('jet')
    normed_topo = (topo - cmin) / (cmax - cmin)
    mapped_topo = my_cm(normed_topo)                # => REMOVES MY NAN VALUES
    # which will give a MxNx4 array mapped between 0 and 1,
    mapped_topou8 = (255 * mapped_topo).astype('float32')
    r, g, b = mapped_topou8[:, :, 1], mapped_topou8[:, :, 2], mapped_topou8[:, :, 3]

    # HOW TO DEAL WITH NAN ?
    # Find indices that I need to replace
    inds = np.where(np.isnan(topo))
    # Place column means in the indices. Align the arrays using take
    r[inds] = np.nan
    g[inds] = np.nan
    b[inds] = np.nan
    # Convert to uint8 - IS IT USEFUL?
    r = r.astype('uint8')
    g = g.astype('uint8')
    b = b.astype('uint8')

    # geotransform needs coordinates of one corner and the resolution of the file
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [lon.min(), lat.min(), lon.max(), lat.max()]
    nrows, ncols = np.shape(topo)
    xres = (xmax - xmin) / float(ncols)
    yres = (ymax - ymin) / float(nrows)
    geotransform = (xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, -yres)
    # That's (top left x, w-e pixel resolution, rotation (0 if North is up),
    #         top left y, rotation (0 if North is up), n-s pixel resolution)

    # Create the 3-band raster file
    output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(sspath, ncols, nrows, 3, gdal.GDT_Float32)
    output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)  # Specify its coordinates
    srs = osr.SpatialReference()                 # Establish its coordinate encoding
    srs.ImportFromEPSG(3857)                     # This one specifies WGS84 lat long

    output_raster.SetProjection(srs.ExportToWkt())  # Exports the coordinate system to the file
   output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(r)    # Write r-band to the raster
    output_raster.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(g)    # Write g-band to the raster
    output_raster.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(b)    # Write b-band to the raster
    output_raster.FlushCache()                      # Write to disk.
```

Comment: I can't give a full answer right now, but basically you need to use a placeholder value for the NaN's and call `SetNoDataValue(placeholder_val)` for each band.  `uint8`'s can't hold NaN's (which are fundementally a floating point value).

Comment: Could `numpy.nan_to_num` help? It will set all NaNs to zero.

Comment: Actually, I just notice that you're creating a 3-band, 32-bit float tiff.  In that case, you should be able to leave the NaN's in (just don't convert your bands to uint8).  However, a lot of GIS software won't handle NaN's correctly in some cases.  Therefore, you may still want to replace your NaN's with a placeholder (e.g. -9999) and call `SetNoDataValue`.

Comment: I removed the part: _"Convert to uint8"_ and replaced the `nan` values by `-99` and finally, as suggested above, I called `SetNoDataValue` for each band. It works pretty well and my GIS tool does recognize the missing values.