# How to save a greyscale matplotlib plot to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

For example, I plot a figure using matplotlib as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(output_fig, zorder=0,cmap="gray")
plt.scatter(x,y,color='k')
```

if I use:

```
plt.savefig(figname,fotmat=figtype)
```

I will save it as a figure file. However, I want so save it to a matrix, or numpy array, such that each element saves the scale value of each pixel  of the figure.
How can I do this?
I find solutions saving the RGB values. But I hope to save a greyscale figure.
Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to convert pyplot.imshow() object to numpy array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14869321/is-there-a-way-to-convert-pyplot-imshow-object-to-numpy-array)

Comment: @umutto Not exactly the same. I'm looking forward to a solution for greyscale figure, not RGB figure. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you have a ploted data (self contained example bellow):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, color

img = data.camera()

x = np.random.rand(100) * img.shape[1]
y = np.random.rand(100) * img.shape[0]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img,cmap="gray")
plt.scatter(x, y, color='k')
plt.ylim([img.shape[0], 0])
plt.xlim([0, img.shape[1]])
```

The underlying data can be recovered as array by using `fig.canvas` (the matplotlib's canvas). First trigger its drawing:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Get the data as array:

```
width, height = fig.get_size_inches() * fig.get_dpi()
mplimage = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype='uint8').reshape(height, width, 3)
```

If you want your array to be the same shape as the original image you will have to play with `figsize` and `dpi` properties of `plt.figure()`.

Last, matplotlib returns an RGB image, if you want it grayscale:

```
gray_image = color.rgb2gray(mplimage)
```